# Open full URL in jmeter which return in previous response

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have response which return full url e.g. redirectUrl=https://myurl:9999/path/path2?a=b
I want to submit a sampler without parsing it, as it is.
Can it be done in jmeter or jmeter plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Extract the URL from the response using i.e. [Regular Expression Extractor](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter) and store it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html), i.e. use `redirectUrl` as the "Reference Name"
2. Add another [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and put `${redirectUrl}` into "Path" section:

   [image: JMeter URL as Path]
3. JMeter is smart enough to build a proper HTTP request from the URL provided via "Path" section:

   [image: JMeter URL from Path]

Comment: I'm using Jmeter 3.1. It failed because http:// added to URL automatically, 
   exception:    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host may not be blank
 at org.apache.http.util.Args.notBlank(Args.java:74)
 at org.apache.http.cookie.CookieOrigin.<init>(CookieOrigin.java:51)
 at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.HC4CookieHandler.getCookiesForUrl(HC4CookieHandler.java:216)
 at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.HC4CookieHandler.getCookieHeaderForURL(HC4CookieHandler.java:166)